# Use class names to load corresponding image paths

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I write javascript that iterates through a table, grabs the class, and then replaces with an image?  So for example I have a table with columns that have numeric classes appended to them:

```
<td class="images 12-345"></td>
<td class="images 98-763"></td>
```

These numbers coorelate with image names that I want to load with javascript after the rest of the query is finished processing. So the final product would look like :

```
<td class="images 12-345"><img src="http://site.com/12-345.jpg"></td>
<td class="images 98-763"><img src="http://site.com/98-763.jpg"></td>
```

But not until everything is done loading.  I would like to just have a placeholder graphic in there that is replaced with the correct image file after everything has processed.

How would I iterate through these rows and then load the appropriate image to each cell?  I was thinking first I could use the .images selector to retrieve each unique numeric class name and pass that into a variable.  Then with that variable I could append it to the rest of the image path and place it back into its appropriate table cell.  I would not want this to begin processing until the rest of the dom had finished loading and the original sql query had completed.  Can I please have some advice on what would be the best way to write this.  jQuery is an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this with jQuery:

```
$('td.images').each(function() {
    var $td     = $(this);
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    var num     = $.grep(classes, function(c) { return c.match(/^[\d-]+$/) });
    if(num.length)
        $td.append('<img src="http://site.com/' + num[0] + '.jpg">');
});
```

Demo (with just the numbers in the cells): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/vrDvc/1/

You might need to adjust the `$.grep` and how you handle the `num` array to match your real data but the basic technique should work.

Comment: Thanks I will try that.  I just realized my example is no good though because the class is not just numbers, they are hyphenated.  I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Zac: That format just needs a small tweak to the regex, have a look at my update please.

Comment: Thanks!  That is cool, and does what I asked.  Doesnt fix my problem though.. I thought by loading with script like this that it would stop crashing the browser but the number or requests still seems to be overwhelming it.  Back to the drawing board.  Thanks for your help.